# How can I wire a thermocouple to monitor wood stove catalytic converter?

Tags: wiring, woodstove, thermocouple

Many modern wood stoves (wood *space-heaters*, actually) use a catalytic converter to dramatically increase efficiency and dramatically reduce pollution.   It's important for users to monitor the temperature of the converter (also called a combustor), primarily because it must be brought up to an initial temperature of 500 degrees-F or so before engaging the bypass damper that forces the smoke to go *through* the combustor (as opposed to bypassing it and going straight out the chimney).

The temperature is normally monitored with a crude thermometer based on a coil spring and a probe that extends a few inches down into the stovetop just above the combustor.  I've had considerable problems with these devices failing, and I also think it'd simply be fun to use a more modern approach.  Thus, I'm considering the use of a thermocouple and solicit thoughts on the viability of this approach.

I've found a device called the "Type K" thermocouple, that seems like it could fit the bill.   They can handle temperatures of at least 2500 degrees-F; the combustor normally operates in the 1000-2000 degrees-F range, and almost never above 2000 (furthermore, guarding against such excessive temperatures is another reason for monitoring temperature).   They have a sensitivity of about 20 microvolts per degree-F, easily monitored.

https://assets.omega.com/pdf/tables_and_graphs/thermocouple-type-k-fahrenheit.pdf

I suppose the biggest concern is protecting the wiring between the thermcouple-proper and the measuring device (a cheap DVM, or perhaps an Arduino), as well as the measuring device itself.   The latter problem can be solved by distance, as the wiring would be carrying no current to speak of, and the voltages are high enough (roughly 10-50 mv in the range of interest) that EM interference is unlikely to be of concern.

Which leaves the wiring.  The Type K thermocouples seem to be geared towards kiln users.   These have comparable temperatures to the wood combustor, but the exterior is well-insulated from the hot area, whereas just the opposite is the case for a wood heater.  So it's not clear if the wiring can survive the stovetop temperatures, and if not, how it might be protected.  Here's an image which shows the basic situation.   The gloved finger points to the tiny hole where the probe would be inserted.  I imagine the wiring extending to the rear (near the flue collar where the stovepipe attaches) to the block wall behind the stove (tan stucco, barely visible in the photo)  The top of the stove and the flue pipe should not exceed 1000 degrees-F or so.

[image]

No doubt it'd work to suspend (in the air) the wiring between the themocouple and the stucco'd block wall that surrounds the stove, but it'd be awkward and unsightly.

So, is the some way of providing the interconnect that can easily survive the stovetop temperature ?   Any other concerns about the efficacy of this approach ?

Comment: So they come with varying lengths - is 3 metres good enough: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/automation-control-gear/sensors/thermocouples/?applied-dimensions=4294876438

Comment: I've bought a few thermocouples, and the insulation has always been rated to the same temperature as the whole thing - in fact it's usually the limit.  The connector is flimsy plastic because it's designed to be near the cold junction and your measuring electronics.  So buy one with long enough cable to go all the way and you'll be fine.

Comment: Minor correction:  that's 20 microvolts per degree F, right?

Comment: @JoelKeene Ah yes, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

Thermocouple wiring must only be extended using the same material which the Thermocouple itself is made of.

Since a Thermocouple is formed simply by the junction of 2 dissimilar conductors (nickel alloys alumel & chromel for Type-K), using normal copper wire to extend your Thermocouple will actually create another 2 Thermocouples - one in series with each wire - which could have a significant impact on the accuracy of your readings.

So for your application, you need to find thermocouple extension wire with insulation which is rated to withstand the 2000F temperature - it'll probably be glass-fiber mesh since silicone and teflon don't go that high.
You'll also obviously need to make sure that the Thermocouple itself is made with insulation rated for that temperature!
If the connection between the Thermocouple wire and the extension is also going to be subjected to high temperatures then you'll probably need to use something like ceramic-body screw terminal blocks. In this case you'll want to make sure that the wires from each side extend all the way through so that you're only really relying on the terminal block to mechanically clamp the wires to each other (as opposed to having it become "part of the circuit").

Comment: Wow, ok, that makes it trickier.   I'd say 1000F is good for the extension wire though (not 2000).

Comment: At some point I need to connect a DVM to the wiring, to measure the voltage (and thus temperature).  How does that fit in with the wiring needing to be the same material ?   Or can I not use an ordinary DVM, and instead need a device specifically meant for use with a Type K ?

Comment: There are many DVMs which are capable of performing thermocouple measurements and displaying the result in temperature units rather than volts - I'd assumed you were referring to one like that in your question. Similarly, thermocouple amplifiers for the Arduino ecosystem are common. These both typically perform the "cold junction compensation" appropriately to take care of the dissimilar materials and also "know" the correct scaling & linearization factors for the particular thermocouple type being used.

Comment: A wrong-metal terminal block wouldn't create a major measurement inaccuracy, would it - since it would be two thermocouples in series, with opposite polarity and thermally coupled?

Comment: Long conversation with gentleman at a vendor.    He mentioned that he had a customer use a TypeK to measure exhaust gas temperature, and that the exhaust gas was hydrogen-rich and this destroyed the thermocouple within a couple weeks.    I mentioned I'd be using it *above* the combustor, not directly in the exhaust stream, and he thought that might be ok.   But he also mentioned a Type N thermocouple might be better,

Comment: @user253751 yes - the opposite thermocouple junctions in series with a 'wrong-metal' terminal block *should* cancel out, particularly since the temperature at each junction would be the same (the distance from one screw to the other being very small). But ensuring that the wires being connected do actually directly touch each other is very low effort and means that you can just pretend the junctions aren't there.

Comment: @brhans That makes sense, but seems to contradict the first sentence of your answer above.

Comment: @RustyShackleford no, not really. Extending a thermocouple with 'normal' wire creates only a single extra junction in each wire, and that junction never gets cancelled out. Using a dissimilar metal junction block say it's copper for example, creates a alumel-copper junction, followed immediately by an opposite copper-alumel junction, and both these junctions are at the same temperature, so they cancel each other out. Similarly on the other wire the chromel-copper and copper-chromel junctions cancel out....

Comment: ... Using copper wire to extend, you have a single alumel-copper junction on one side, and a single chromel-copper junction on the other side - those junctions are not the same and won't cancel each other.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if I really need to go with Type N (instead of K).   Sounds like lots of them are encased in some kind of sheath, so maybe corrosion (from the flue gasses) could be avoided that way ?